# Do any of L.E. Modesitt's worlds cross over?

Tags: crossovers, l-e-modesitt

Several of L.E. Modesitt's series involve some kind of dimensional travel - Spellsong Cycle connects to modern Earth, Recluse has travelers from whereever the angels of darkness and demons of light were fighting (and at least one person from Earth), and I remember it coming up in The Corean Chronicles as well.

Do any of these series (or any of his other books) actually cross over with something else he's written, either series or standalone?